# Configuration of Axon Framework 4.2 without Spring Boot

Tags: configuration, axon

I'm new to Axon framework. I'm evaluating it with Axon Server.

Using Spring Boot is very convenient und worked right away.

Problem is, we are aiming at using Spring Boot processes tied together with non Spring Boot processes (Hybris Commerce from SAP).

My question is: What do I have to do to configure Axon framework 4.2 without Spring Boot? (Without Spring Boot the AxonServerAutoConfiguration does not work).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Axon provides the Configuration API, which as been given its [own module](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/tree/master/config) as of release 4.
This package contains the `Configurer`, `AggregateConfigurer`, `EventProcessingConfigurer` and `SagaConfigurer` which should give you all the handles to define any set up with buses, aggregates and query models.

The [Reference Guide](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/) typically provides snippets on how to configure a given component, both through the Configuration API and Spring Boot as separate code tabs.

Additionally, it's sensible that the `AxonServerAutoConfiguration` does not work without Spring Boot, as it's a Spring Boot dedicated solution to configuring your application.
Even without it though, Axon will (through a Service Loader mechanism) auto-load the `ServerConnectorConfigurerModule` once you've created a default `Configurer`. This should give you the required infrastructure components to configure an application using Axon Server without utilizing Spring Boot.